# Is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

this [post](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~linear/old/notes17.pdf) says

[image]

> Since U is only two vectors, it is clear that U is not a vector space.

if I add zero-vector into U

$$
U^{'} = 
\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\}
\subset R^3
$$

Is $(U^{'}, +)$ a vector space?

Comment: You must specify over what **field** are you talking...though the answer won't change in this particular case. But it could in other examples.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks for your comments. I've updated the post. is that now you suggested?

Comment: Isn't this question too simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $$U'=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ is not a vector space. And it is not, because this set contains the element $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\in U'$$ but it does not contain $$2\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\notin U'$$

which means it does not satisfy all conditions a vector space should satisfy.

Comment: @DonAntonio It was a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Still not.

It isn't closed under addition (or scalar multiplication).  Either one of these would preclude it from being a vector space.

That is (to consider the addition part): $\begin {pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin {pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end {pmatrix}\not\in U'$.

Answer (score 2):

No finite subset $F$ of $\mathbb R^3$ other than $\bigl\{\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^T\bigr\}$ is a vector space, because if $v\in F$ is a non-null vector, then $nv\notin F$ if $n\in\mathbb N$ is large enough.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is there a way to write $F$ in the vector set form?

Comment: @fuDL What is "vector set form"?

Comment: the set of vectors, like this, $U'=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Comment: Since $F$ is a finite set of **vectors**, yes,

Answer (score 0):

No. Except for the $0$-dimensional space $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ there is no finite vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

What you wrote down is not even a vector, but a matrix.

Assuming that you just wanted to add the zero vector, it is still not a vector space as for example $(2,0,0) \not \in U'$, but $(1,0,0) \in U'$. This means that $U'$ Is not closed under scalar multiplication.